# Effects of lenses

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses

I have three convex lenses that I'm arranging so as to function as a crude magnification device. My question is about the image that I see. It seems that no matter how I arrange them, with respect to their distance from one another or to the placement front or back of the lens, the image is inverted. The lenses are from an old big screen TV.  I'm thinking that the proper arrangement should get the image up-righted, but not yet. Is there a known value equation for the spacing or orientation to make this possible?

Comment: I have to ask before answering. Do you need the image to be real? Or can it be virtual and not need to be formed on a screen and it's okay for it to be just seen using the eye?

Comment: Its ok to be seen only by the user of the lenses directly. It does not need to be displayed on a screen

Comment: We mean: do you need to see the image **on something** (whatever it is, hte image is projected) , or do you want the image to be seen only looking into the lens, like a magnifyer glass?

Comment: @FGSUZ Of course, you can still see real images by looking onto the lens ...

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I said **only looking onto**. I know, but I didn't figure out how else to explain in a didactic way what real and virtual images are, as the asker doesn't seem to be very familiar with lenses, but I might be wrong.

Comment: The only requirement for my particular question is to view the image like looking into a telescope (one like a hollywood pirate would have had)

Comment: And you  are correct I am green as grass when it comes to lenses.